# Http POST request with multipart/form-data using clj-ajax

Tags: ajax, clojure, clojurescript

I have an endpoint where I can upload a text file with curl like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@/resources/speciesDiffusion.tree" http://localhost:4000/continuous/tree
```

now I need to send a similar request from a browser, but

```
 (ajax/ajax-request
  {:uri (str "http://localhost:4000" "/continuous/tree")
   :method :post
   :params {:treefile file}
   :handler #(println %1)
   :format (ajax/text-request-format)
   :response-format (ajax/json-response-format {:keywords? true})})
```

gives me a (nicely json converted, so I got that part going, which is nice) error response:

```
[false {:status 500, :status-text , :failure :error, :response {:timestamp 1494279686227, :status 500, :error Internal Server Error, :exception org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException, :message Current request is not a multipart request, :path /continuous/tree}}]
```

Also, in the browser I can see that the content-type headers is not correctly set, but I couldn't get it to work with any other combination of   :format and :params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some examples in the README of the cljs-ajax project. For example:

```
(let [form-data (doto
                    (js/FormData.)
                  (.append "id" "10")
                  (.append "file" js-file-value "filename.txt"))]
  (POST "/send-file" {:body form-data
                      :response-format (raw-response-format)
                      :timeout 100}))
```

https://github.com/JulianBirch/cljs-ajax

Comment: Thank you, but I am well aware of the existing documentation, which unfortunately doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I suggest another read then because your example doesn't specify a `:body` or any `:headers`

Comment: As per official documentation:                                                           :params - the parameters that will be sent with the request, format dependent: :transit and :edn can send anything, :json and :raw need to be given a map. GET will add params onto the query string, POST will put the params in the body.

Comment: OK. But that's not true of a multipart POST, as I've demonstrated and as the documentation implies.

Comment: the problem was actually a little different - I was sending a file content (as read with js/FileReaders onLoad event), instead of simply a js file.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment the problem was not in the request, but rather in the f-tion that dispatched it, i.e. I was reading the file content instead of sending the raw object like here:

```
(defn handle-file-upload [evt]
  (let [target (.-currentTarget evt)
        js-file (-> target .-files (aget 0))]
    (do
      (re-frame/dispatch [:post-file {:file js-file
                                                 :name (.-name js-file)}])
      (set! (.-value target) ""))))

(defn upload-button []
  (fn []
[:input {:class "none"
             :id "file-upload"
             :type "file"
             :on-change #(handle-file-upload %)}]))
```

where

> :post-file

is an event which invokes the handler which does the POST request.